# How to inovke one lambda form another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a S3 bucket that have inside a multiple folders. In this folder there will be a multiple files. I have crated a lambda that will execute a procedure in Snowflake. The main goal of this procedure is to load to raw data table a values from CSV files that are in S3 bucket. The lambda function can work only 15 minutes. I need a lot more. So I'm thinking that I can load data from s3 bucket to Snowflake per one folder. (loading data from one folder takes me over 11 minutes) So for example in S3 bucket I will have folder Test_1, Test_2.. in this folders I will have files file_1,file_2 etc. So how to invoke another lambda from one lambda so I can load data only per one folder? The number of lambdas will be the same as number of folders. So it can change every day

Comment: it's pointless to try do this, just use Snowpipe if you don't have long running servers to run some node/python/cron stuff on. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have considered a Snowpipe but in snowpipe I don't know when the specific file will be loaded. So I can't use that

Comment: You can consider ECS for long running tasks like this. You can schedule tasks based on time, like cron or configure to run based on event.

Comment: Yes, a Lambda function can invoke other Lambda functions, synchronously or asynchronously, using the AWS SDK of your choice, but this is often not an ideal approach to solving problems of orchestration around Lambda and S3. You might also consider Step Functions or even S3 Batch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SNS to trigger the same or another Lambda function. The first Lambda function could publish an SNS notification with the context/state information in the notification message. The second Lambda function, which could be the same Lambda, could subscribe to the SNS topic.

If the second Lambda is the same as the first Lambda, you must ensure that there would never be the case of infinite recursive calls.